# AVCaptureSession with BluetoothHFP device

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I need to stream the voice data to server, so I can't use AVAudioRecorder.
Here is my approach.

set it Allow Bluetooth and activate it

```
NSError* e;
AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord
                                     withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                                           error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES withOptions:0 error:&e];
```

I did setup the notification for AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
so I see the input source changed to BluetoothHFP

but seems there is no way to configure a BluetoothHFP input to AVCaptureDeviceInput.

```
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
        self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;

    AVCaptureDevice* captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    AVCaptureDeviceInput* audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

    if(audioInput && [self.captureSession canAddInput:audioInput]){
        [self.captureSession addInput:audioInput];
    }
```

after doing so, the input source changed to iPhone MicroPhone.

is there anyway I can get the BluetoothHFP input as AVCaptureDeviceInput??

Comment: Set the capture session's `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` property to NO.

Comment: it works!!! thanks