# Output AVCaptureSession to iPhone speaker

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I'm fairly new to Swift programming, and I am trying to make a simple Microphone app. If you have your phone connected to a bluetooth speaker, I want the audio you speak into the microphone to come out through the speaker. I think I have the input working, but I can't get the output to play on whatever device the iphone has access to (its own speaker or a bluetooth speaker if connected)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MicVC: UIViewController, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var offButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var onButton: UIButton!

    let onColor = UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 17/255, blue: 7/255, alpha: 1.0)


    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100]
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "AudioSessionQueue", attributes: [])
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)
    var audioInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput? = nil
    var audioOutput : AVCaptureAudioDataOutput? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        onButton.backgroundColor = .orange
        offButton.backgroundColor = .gray

        onButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        offButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        output.connection(with: AVMediaType(rawValue: AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker))

        print("Audio data received")

    //        audioOutput = output as? AVCaptureAudioDataOutput
    //        audioOutput?.connection(with: .audio)

    }

    @IBAction func stopPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        onButton.backgroundColor = .orange
        offButton.backgroundColor = .gray

        captureSession.stopRunning()
        print("stop")
    }

    @IBAction func onPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        onButton.backgroundColor = .white
        offButton.backgroundColor = onColor


        do {
            try captureDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
            audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
            captureDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
            print(captureDevice!)
            audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
            audioOutput?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    //                audioOutput?.audioSettings = settings
            } catch {
                print("Capture devices could not be set")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        if audioInput != nil && audioOutput != nil {
            captureSession.beginConfiguration()
            if (captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput!)) {
                captureSession.addInput(audioInput!)
            } else {
                print("cannot add input")
            }
            if (captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput!)) {
                captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput!)
            } else {
                print("cannot add output")
            }
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()

            print("Starting capture session")
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324703/avcapturesession-with-bluetoothhfp-device#comment91596662_52324703

Comment: thanks! that seems to be for input though, is there a similar process to set the output?